# Programatically Change Folder Content Type JAVA

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-type, microsoft-graph, java

I need to Programatically be able to change the content type of the folders in a SharePoint Online Site.

I have Java Program that needs to run and detect if a folder has the correct Content Type and if not Change it.

This is how i have been triying to do it.

```
SiteRequestBuilder site = graphClient.sites(siteId);

ContentType tfct = null;

for (ContentType contentType : site.lists(listId).contentTypes().buildRequest().get().getCurrentPage()) {
    if (contentType.name.equalsIgnoreCase("Tagged Folder")) {
        tfct = contentType;
        break;
    }
}
```

Here i detect and search for the Content Type i want the folder to have.

Then i do a recursive crawl by all the items, and if i detect the item is a folder i then need to change the content type.

```
    request = graphClient
            .drives(driveId)
            .items(itemId)
            .children()
            .buildRequest();

DriveItemCollectionPage driveItems = request.get();
for (DriveItem driveItem :driveItems.getCurrentPage()){
    if (driveItem.folder != null) {
        ListItem listItem = graphClient.drives(driveId).items(driveItem.id).listItem().buildRequest().get();

                if(!listItem.contentType.id.equalsIgnoreCase(tfct.id)){
                    listItem.contentType.id = tfct.id;
                    graphClient.sites(siteId).lists(listId).items(listItem.id).buildRequest().patch(listItem);
                }
    }
}
```

But now when i run this code i get

```
[2024-03-25 21:28:04.253] ERROR  main            com.mcm.sharepoint.SharePointTaggerUtil           Error listing drive items: Error code: invalidRequest
Error message: Invalid request
```

Any one can give me a hand on either what is wrong or how can i change the ContentType and post it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by following the tips in this page
https://brettmckenzie.net/posts/updating-a-sharepoint-list-items-content-type-in-the-microsoft-graph/

So what i needed to do, was create a new ListItem with the fields i wanted to change and then do a patch on the item with this new listItem.

Here is the step by step guide.

1. First find the content Type by looking in the list where your item to update it.
2. Once you have it create a ContentTypeInfo Object and add the id and name to it.
3. Create a new ListItem Object and add the contentTypeInfo created to the contentType propertie
4. Patch to the listItem.

In this code bellow tfct is of the type ContentType

```
                ContentTypeInfo contentTypeInfo = new ContentTypeInfo();
                contentTypeInfo.id = tfct.id;
                contentTypeInfo.name = tfct.name;
                
                ListItem listItemNewInfo = new ListItem();
                listItemNewInfo.contentType = contentTypeInfo;

                graphClient.drives(driveId).items(driveItem.id).listItem().buildRequest().patch(listItemNewInfo);
```